# How to prevent Composer from using global core.autocrlf config on Windows

Tags: git, composer-php, core.autocrlf

I have a private git repo configured in my `composer.json` file.

I am trying to require a package from it, however I want composer to checkout the repository with `lf` line endings.

I want to keep my global `core.autocrlf` set to true.

Is there any way to tell composer to run the git clone command with autocrlf set to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found if I add

```
* text eol=lf
```

to `.gitattributes` it checks out correctly